# How do you use mod_rewrite for a custom variable node with a Drupal system that is already using clean URLs?

Tags: variables, url, mod-rewrite, drupal, clean-urls

Situation setup: 
-Drupal 7
-Clean URLs have been enabled inside Drupal, and they are working
-The stock .htaccess in the root and subdirectory are unmodified. (I have the Drupal install sitting in a directory called 'main'.)
-Shared hosting environment
-Custom Drupal node/page that is accepting a variable and then performing some php work on that variable.
-In my case the variable identifies an event, and the page pulls data from the database to generated information about that event.

Actual URL that was in use and working:

```
http://nasarallysport.com/main/event?e=2014-Black-River-Stages
```

Desired URL:

```
http://nasarallysport.com/main/event/2014-Black-River-Stages
```

So, on the face of it, it would seem that this would be a fairly straightforward mod_rewrite.

RewriteRule ^.*event/(.*)$ main/event?e=$1 [NC,L]

I tested this out via the htaccess simulator here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it correctly detected the url and generated the first link listed above.

However, it totally doesn't work. So, to be clear, mod_rewrite IS enabled, IS processing, IS doing what I think it is, IS making the correct URL behind the scenes, but Drupal is giving out 404 like nobody's business.

Oh, and to make things even more frustrating, there **is** a mod_rewrite log generation command. But you can't enable it with .htaccess, so if you're on shared hosting, you just **won't** be doing any debugging via the logs. You're pretty much going to be stuck in a "try something, oh, look, the entire site is now Error 500, Apache Internal Server Error, undo, try something else loop." So unless you have root, don't bother googling how to turn on logging.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to ignore the clean URLs. You need to generate the **UNCLEAN** URL to get this to work. Essentially, YOU can't go making clean URLs and then expect Drupal to turn them into their "real" URL. So, the easiest way is to go into the Drupal admin, turn Clean URLs **off**, go see what the URL for that node is, and then set up your mod_rewrite rule to create that "regular" URL.

> RewriteRule ^.*event/(.*)$ main/?q=event&e=$1 [NC,L]

Which will generate this URL:

```
http://nasarallysport.com/main/?q=event&e=2014-Black-River-Stages
```

And THAT will do what you want it to. The node name that I had for this page was "event".

For total clarity, here is the entire mod_rewrite section inside the .htaccess in the /main directory. I removed the stock commented out lines just to make it sorter here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
  # RewriteBase /

  # ##############################################################
  # AG: You cannot rewrite to a drupal clean url, it won't find it
  # The line below is the only line added or changed.
  # ##############################################################
  RewriteRule ^.*event\/(.*)$ main/?q=event&e=$1 [NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

However, you're **still** not quite out of the woods yet. Yes, the page works. However, Drupal will set the canonical header tag to the equivalent of:

```
http://www.nasarallysport.com/main/event
```

Which is, after all correct. Soooo, if you (or anyone else) tries to drop that link on Facebook, Facebook **will** use the canonical URL. And pulling that page, without the variables you want to pass it, means that the Facebook **preview** will be all wrong, even though the link will still click through to the correct place.

The way that I fixed this is to use the Facebook Open Graph meta tags. There's title, url, organization, image, and site name, which you can explore, but here's the URL fix, this was added to the code inside the Drupal node which was the 'event' page:

```
$element2 = array
    (
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array
        ( 
        'property' => 'og:url',
        'content' => "http://NASARallySport.com/main/event/$eventCoding",
        ),
    );
drupal_add_html_head($element2, 'og_url');
```

$eventCoding had been set, after processing, to 2014-Black-River-Stages so now Facebook will use the proper URL to generate it's preview.

Changing the Drupal-generated "canonical' header tag would probably work too, but when I tried it, it didn't un-set so I moved on.